# Will docker-compose allow mapping a port to two ports or do I need an ambassador?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ports

Suppose I have an application that listens on `8888` - other parts of the application want to continue to access it on `8888` - but the external users need to access it at a port range above 50000 - eg `50888`.

What I'd like to do in my `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
ports:
  - "8888:8888"
  - "50888:8888"
```

Will this work?

My other alternative is to add an [ambassador](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/ambassador_pattern_linking/) in there like this:

```
blah:
  image: blah:6
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  container_name: blah
  networks:
    default: {}
blah_ambassador:
  image: svendowideit/ambassador
  links:
    - blah
  ports:
    - "50888:8888"
  environment:
    - BLAH_PORT_8888_TCP:tcp://blah:8888 
  container_name: ops_ambassador
  networks:
    default: {}
```

My question is: **Will docker-compose allow mapping a port to two ports or do I need an ambassador?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago, docker-compose used a dictionary to store the mapping ports and the key was the internal port, so one value overrode the other.

This was fixed [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/624) using a list. So, currently, docker-compose allows mapping an internal port to two ports. Maybe you are using an older docker-compose version.

Example:

```
→ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
```

Docker-compose file content (`docker-compose.yml`):

```
backend:
  image: your_image
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
    - 8888:3000
```

docker inspect command: `docker inspect your_container_id`

```
"Ports": {
            "3000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8888"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "3000"
                }
            ]
        },
```